# Do Rewarded Products mark the app as "Contains ads"?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

If I add **Rewarded Products** to an application in the Google Play Console, does this mark the app as "Contains ads" in the Play Store?

I could not find an answer in the [Play Console help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9155268?hl=en) nor anywhere else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Comment: So? It isn't on-topic.

Comment: The lack of an official customer support channel does not make this any more on-topic. As for where you can ask, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first paragraph of the link you provided is this:

*Diversify your **ads** monetization strategy using rewarded products. Your users can choose to watch a short **advertisement** and, upon completion, they will receive a rewarded product such as virtual goods or in-game currency.*

So I would say YES. It definitely marks your app as "Contains ads".

Comment: You are right, I asked support and they confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

`Contains ads` on Google Play Store is something you as a developer set. In your Google Play Console, navigate to

```
Apps > Store presence > Pricing & Distribution
```

[image]

So, if you app is showing any kind of ad be it native, banner, interstitial or rewarded, you'll have to set `Yes`, if you don't, not only the ads will be stopped serving on your app but also your app may get suspended by Google for violating their policy.

Comment: Well, it is neither a banner nor an interstitial because the user has to choose to open such an ad. I think that I will just ask support.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Did you ask support team about this, what they said?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot OK no worries, but the answer you accepted is kinda same which I gave you before, however I just noticed you have good time with me on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Support said that I need to set "Yet, it has ads".

Comment: Thanks, and this is what I also wrote in my answer.